# Watching network usage level from Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, networking

I'm currently looking for a way, how to get real-time data about network utilization from Java. I would like to see how several running threads (all downloading stuff from web) utilize network and simultaneously be able to set threshold for spawning new threads if some criteria are not met. Let's say I create 10 threads, all downloading some stuff from web, and network utilization would be on 5%, consider previously set threshold to max utilization of 10%, I would be allowed to spawn a new thread. Thing is, I'm not sure if there's a way how to get such network information. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is likely to be OS-specific. Which OS(es) do you need to support?

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to write that I'm developing this on Windows. I modified topic name ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux, you should be able to read this information from a system file in `/proc/net`. For example, `/proc/net/dev`:

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo: 108751031  226504    0    0    0     0          0         0 108751031  226504    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0: 113355689  146027    0    0    0     0          0         0 18453619  122751    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

This file is easy to read in pretty much any programming language, including Java.

**Note:** the question has now been changed to explicitly refer to Windows. So this is no longer a fully appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's really useful. Is there how to do something like that on Windows?

Comment: I stopped using Windows way over 10 years ago. But it never had the Unix philosophy of "everything is a file" that encouraged this style of system APIs on Linux. I believe you'll have to use some native DLL to get the equivalent data, but maybe someone already wrote a JNI for this.